# Type hierarchy definition in Coq or Agda

Tags: coq, agda

I would like to build a kind of type hierarchy:

```
B is of type A  ( B::A )

C and D are of type of B   (C,D ::B) 

E and F are of type of C     (E,F ::C)
```

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26902472/edit) if this is possible to be directly implemented in Isabelle, but the answer as you see was No. Is it possible to encode this directly in Agda or Coq?

PS: Suppose A..F are all abstract and some functions are defined over each type)

Thanks

Comment: No, What I am interested in is type hierarchy, I used "::" notation for specifying the typing relationship: by "C::B" and "B::A" I mean  that C is typed over B and B is typed over A, respectively. So I am interested to see if type hierarchy is directly possible in Agda/Coq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want something that looks like [the identity type](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/html/Relation.Binary.Core.html#4603). When we declare the type constructor `_isOfType_`, we mention two `Set`s (the parameter `A` and the index `B`) but the constructor `indeed` makes sure that the only way to construct an element of such a type is to enforce that they are indeed equal (and that `a` is of this type):

```
data _isOfType_ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} (a : A) : (B : Set ℓ) → Set where
  indeed : a isOfType A
```

We can now have functions taking as arguments proofs that things are of the right type. Here I translated your requirements & assumed that I had a function `f` able to combine two `C`s into one. Pattern-matching on the appropriate assumptions reveals that E and F are indeed on type `C` and can therefore be fed to `f` to discharge the goal:

```
example : ∀ (A : Set₃) (B : Set₂) (C D : Set₁) (E F : Set) →
    B isOfType A
  → C isOfType B → D isOfType B
  → E isOfType C → F isOfType C
  → (f : C → C → C) → C
example A B .Set D E F _ _ _ indeed indeed f = f E F
```

Do you have a particular use case in mind for this sort of patterns or are you coming to Agda with ideas you have encountered in other programming languages? There may be a more idiomatic way to formulate your problem.

Comment: Thanks gallais, I describe the problem here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926632/defining-disjoint-union-of-different-types-in-isabelle-and-more)